# characterization of quotient rings

Tags: abstract-algebra

In the ring $\mathbb{Q}{[x]}$ consider the following subset

$I = \{f(x) (x^2 + 3) | f(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]\}$

Prove that $I$ is an ideal in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ and express the quotient ring $\mathbb{Q}[x]/I$.

First I'm not sure of all the conditions to verify to be sure in an ideal.

I verified $I$ is an additive subgroup since $f(x)(x^2 + 3) + g(x)(x^2 + 3) = h(x) (x^2 + 3)$ with $h = g + f$.
Then it is also a two-sided ideal $g(x) \cdot f(x)(x^2 + 3)\in I$ with $g \in \mathbb{Q}{[x]}, f(x)(x^2 + 3) \in I$ and $f(x)(x^2 + 3) \cdot g(x) \in I$ as well.

Is it enough, or are there other conditions to be satisfy?

Regarding the characterization of $\mathbb{Q}[x]/I$, I'm uncertain. This should be made of all congruence classes with regards to the equivalence relation ~ defined as:

$g \sim f \quad \iff f - g \in I \quad for \quad g,f \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$

my manual express it as $R/I := \{a+I | a \in \mathbb{Q}[x]\}$

with

$a+I := \{a + i | i \in I \} = \{x \in \mathbb{Q}[x] | x \sim a\}$

Comment: You have to also show that given $f\in I$, $g\in \mathbb Q[x]$, $fg=gf\in I$.

Comment: As for what $\mathbb Q[x]/I$ is, note that all multiples of $x^2+3$ are in the ideal (and they comprise the whole ideal), so they are all equal to $0$ in the quotient ring. So, the quotient ring is simply $\mathbb Q[x]$ under the equivalence $x^2+3=0$, or in other words, $x=i\sqrt3$. So, the quotient ring is $\mathbb Q[i\sqrt3]$.

Comment: hmm..The result should be $\mathbb{Q}[x] / I = \{a+bx+I | a,b \in \mathbb{Q} \}$, maybe it's the same thing as yours but I'm confused about the notation

Comment: When we think about the quotient ring, what we are essentially saying is that we are setting all elements of $I$ to be equal to $0$. The reason why is that we say that two elements are equal if their difference is in $I$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By the division algorithm, for every $p(x) \in \mathbb Q[x]$ there exists $q(x),r(x) \in \mathbb Q[x]$ such that $$p(x) = (x^2+3)q(x)+r(x)$$ and that $\deg r(x) < \deg(x^2+3) = 2$ whenever $r(x) \neq 0$; put in another way: for every $p(x) \in \mathbb Q[x]$ there exists $q(x) \in \mathbb Q[x]$ and $a,b \in \mathbb Q$ such that $p(x) = (x^2+3)q(x)+(a+bx)$, which is the same as saying $$p(x)+I = (a+bx)+I.$$ Thus $\mathbb Q[x]/I = \{(a+bx)+I : a,b \in \mathbb Q\}$.